# Go To selected item in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ListBox which is populated with various data plus the Row number where the data is located, like so:

31-Mar-12 to 15-Apr-12 [Goods A], Row:12009

On a Command Button I need to write code which when clicked will take the user to the specific Row. Column is always fixed at Column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is selected in the listbox it will find the value after the colon (:) and select column 2 of that row number:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim selectedItem As String
    If ListBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        selectedItem = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
        Cells(CInt(Mid(selectedItem, InStrRev(selectedItem, ":") + 1)), 2).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks a million!